# Adding Docusign CustomTabs through API and width is not working

Tags: docusignapi

We are adding Custom Tabs through the API. Once I send the document, the tabs are inserted and all the validations are working as excepted but the width is not working.

**Part of request:**
[image]

**Signing Process:**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the width as part of the custom tab definition? In other words, the custom tab's width may be overriding your setting in the Envelopes: create call.

Answer (score 0):

The text tab width is in pixels. Try setting it to 500 and see if that resolves the issue. Here is more information on  [text tabs](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Text%20Tab.htm)